# How can this function work with click instead of hover?

Tags: jquery, click, hover

I got it this far and I can be OK with this, but ideally I want each section to only show on click, and when the next is clicked, to fade out the current divs and fade in the next respective divs. Seems straightforward, but I can't get it.  Not sure if I need to alter my markup but this felt efficient.

```
    $(document).ready(function() {

    $('.nav li a').hover(function() {

            $(this).siblings('div').stop(true,true).fadeIn()
            },
            function () {
            $(this).siblings('div').stop(true,true).fadeOut()

        });

    });
```

Probably needs context, so here is the fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/5XbrY/

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead

```
$('.nav li a').toggle(
    function() {
        $(this).siblings('div').stop(true,true).fadeIn();
    },
    function () {
        $(this).siblings('div').stop(true,true).fadeOut();
    }
);
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/5XbrY/15/)**

Good Luck !!

Comment: Very nice and so close!  Now I just need to figure out how to get the current set of divs to fade away when another link is clicked and have that set fade in...possibly using find() and next()?

Comment: yes, that is exactly what I need.  One last question:  any reason why it stops working after the second link?  I need to click once more to begin the animation (meaning, I can't click back and forth between the two links).